# Unterminated JSX contents - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    <div>
      <button style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-button pt-intent-primary" onClick="{() => { this.authWithFacebook() }}">Log In with Facebook</button>
      <hr style={{marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px"}}>
      <form onSubmit={(event) => { this.authWithEmailPassword(event) }} ref={(form) => { this.loginForm = form }}>
        <div style={{marginBottom: "10px"}} className="pt-callout pt-icon-info-sign">
          <h5>Note</h5>
          If you dont have an account already, this will create you one!
        </div>
        <label className="pt-label">
          Email
          <input style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-input" name="email" type="email" ref={(input) => {this.emailInput = input}} placeholder="Email"></input>
          Password
          <input style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-input" name="password" type="password" ref={(input) => {this.passwordInput = input}} placeholder="Password"></input>
        </label>
         <input style={{width: "100%"}} type="submit" className="pt-button pt-intent-primary" value="Log In"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Error message:

```
Syntax error: D:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/webWorker/webworker/src/components/Login.js: Unterminated JSX contents (39:14)
```

I do not know what is the problem, it seems to be OK but I cant run it. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Terminate `hr` tag with `<hr />`. `input` tag is also self-closing

Comment: You are not closing `<hr />`

Comment: @boy with silver wings partly, in react you need to do `<input />`

Comment: @JonasW. That is what self closing means. Isn't it?

Comment: Well in html you can do `<input  >` thats why i wanted to outline that before it creates confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to close `<hr />` tag, also you can have the input tags closed `<input />`, since they don't have contents either.

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly about closing the `<hr>` tag. Better would be also to self-close the `<input>` tags like so `<input type="text" />`.
As a bonus I separated the `<label>` tag to each of the input fields, that way whenever you click on the field label it is focusing the right input field.

Before moving on I would recommend to read those two jsx guides: [introduction](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), [advanced](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Your code after modifications:

```
<div>
  <button style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-button pt-intent-primary" onClick="{() => { this.authWithFacebook() }}">Log In with Facebook</button>
  <hr style={{marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px"}} />
  <form onSubmit={(event) => { this.authWithEmailPassword(event) }} ref={(form) => { this.loginForm = form }}>
    <div style={{marginBottom: "10px"}} className="pt-callout pt-icon-info-sign">
      <h5>Note</h5>
      If you dont have an account already, this will create you one!
    </div>
    <label className="pt-label">
      Email
      <input style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-input" name="email" type="email" ref={(input) => {this.emailInput = input}} placeholder="Email"/>
      </label>
    <label className="pt-label">
      Password
      <input style={{width: "100%"}} className="pt-input" name="password" type="password" ref={(input) => {this.passwordInput = input}} placeholder="Password"/>
    </label>
     <input style={{width: "100%"}} type="submit" className="pt-button pt-intent-primary" value="Log In"/>
    </form>
</div>
```